# anyway to make an input autofocus on page load in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, input

I have an SPA where all my components are already rendered on-screen when the page loads. I set a particular input to autofocus and the screen automatically shoots to the component where the input lives, as opposed to staying at the top of the page. Any way to prevent this functionality but keep the input auto or perma focused??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `scrollTo`, hope it helps.

Focus is on last input

```js
class ScrollToTop extends React.Component {
  focus = () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text' / >
      <
      input type = 'text'
      onFocus = {
        this.focus
      }
      autoFocus / >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render( < ScrollToTop / > ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div input {
  outline: none !important;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  width: 50%;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #00b1ff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```